# Does std::discrete_distribution() allow zero weights?

Tags: c++, random

Can [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) be used with some zero weights, assuming that at least one positive weight was given? The items with zero weights should simply never be sampled.

The fact that it appears to work on my machine does not give me confidence that it will work on all systems.

Example:

```
std::discrete_distribution<> dd({1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0});
```

Comment: [weights "shall be non-negative, non-NaN, and non-infinity."](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/numerics.tex#L5769)

Comment: @KamilCuk What you are showing is no weights at all, not some of the weights being zero.

Comment: @BoBTFish That's the answer, thank you.

Comment: A slightly more readable reference: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/rand.dist.samp.discrete#2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [[rand.dist.samp.discrete]/2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/rand.dist.samp.discrete#2)

> Unless specified otherwise, the distribution parameters are calculated as: `pk = wk / S` for `k = 0, ..., n−1`, in which the values wk, commonly known as the weights, shall be non-negative, non-NaN, and non-infinity. Moreover, the following relation shall hold: `0 < S = w0 + ... + wn−1`.

So zero weights are allowed, but not all of the weights can be zero since `S` must be greater than zero.